# NSTimer crash-breakpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I can't figure out what is wrong in code pasted below, im learing xcode with Todd Moore book, this is the chapter 2-hello pong, Im getting breakpoint 1.1 crash at  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval. In book at the end of timer configuration is added ] retain]; but xcode 5 says that's deperecated.I modificate this to compile without retain, but the problem is crash.

```
- (void)animate
{
    _puck.center = CGPointMake(_puck.center.x + dx*speed,_puck.center.y + dy*speed);
}

- (void)start
{
    if (timer == nil) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.016 target:self selector:@selector(animate) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];

    }
    _puck.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are in an ARC setting, automatic reference counting, the object that is doing the animate/start may not be in memory anymore depending on how the rest of the code worked.

If whatever object that is used to have a retain it may not be in memory when that timer gets called.

You may need to do a quick search for how to start a project without automatic reference counting so you can follow the examples in the book more directly.

```
someObject = [[something alloc] init] retain];
[someObject start];
```

If you are not storing someObject somewhere that is likely the problem.

[edit]

I found the source code for that Todd Moore example.

These changes should hopefully let it work with ARC.

get rid of this in PaddlesViewController.h

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

add (near other @properties)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

in PaddlesViewController.m add (near other @synthesize)

```
@synthesize timer;
```

This should allow it to run without the retain

Comment: When the code looks:         timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.016 target:self selector:@selector(animate) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES] retain];
and error "ARC forbides explict message sned of retain"
Timer is defined     NSTimer *timer;

function  start is called in vivwDidLoad >     [self start];

Comment: Like I said if you are learning you need to use the source material more directly.  You need to disable ARC.  1) In build setting set Automatic Reference Counting to NO.  Then you can use retain and release

Comment: after diasble arc, i must to change weak properties to strong, and recompile, but im still getting breakpoint during using retain

Comment: Sorry again.  When turning off arc you might need to add retain to other parts of the code as the book says.  Add - (void)dealloc { [super dealloc]; NSLog("I'm outa here"); }  If you see the text "I'm outa here" before the crash then that means the object is being deallocated too soon.  If it does not them I totally took you in the wrong direction.

Comment: In book there is no information about ARC, but i have translated version, i dont have original version of book. But why, couldnt it works without retain, simply as i showed im my question, why it results in breakpoint?

Comment: The book was most likely written before ARC was made.  ARC is default now.

Comment: I Did, as you led me in this few steps, but it didn't helps, still breakpoint on scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Comment: So, there is any better soultion to perform animation? departing from book code example?